# Enable smooth scrolling on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, release-hera

Scrolling websites on Epiphany is pretty smooth, same as I used to from Windows. This is not the case for Chrome.

I tried enabling the `smooth-scrolling` Chrome flag (though I think it's enabled by default) but that didn't work.

I'm on Dell XPS 13 9530, with 5.1 Hera.

Anyone bumped into it? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smoothscroll/nbokbjkabcmbfdlbddjidfmibcpneigj?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I have two different Dell XPS 13 9370 and 9365.

It seems to me that one of the two, after the update to Hera 5.1, had a little trouble with the Touchpad.

It seems to me that after updating the kernel it solved the problem, in any case I had no problem.

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

Comment: I cleanly installed Hera 5.1, meaning I already got the new kernel. Is the scrolling experience the same on Epiphany & Chrome for you?

Comment: I have Firefox, the kernel does not install automatically with `sudo apt upgrade` the kernel should be` 5.0.0-37-generic` with Hera 5.1, check this with `uname -r`. And yes the experience was good with Epiphany & my Firefox

Comment: got `5.0.0-37-generic` as well, but still can't get smooth-scrolling to work on Chrome..